# Anaconda update for Spyder has failed

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Windows 10, 64 bit Anaconda 4.2, Python 3.5

I opened Spyder today to do some work. (so much for that idea, several hours later)
Spyder gave notice that there was new (3.1) version. I was on 3.0.2
So, I tried updating

conda update spyder

but it told me that it needed to DOWNGRADE it because of dependencies (I think, I wasn't taking notes at the time - so much for optimism)
Then I tried to update conda but that made things worse at this point, Spyder wouldn't start at all.

So, I uninstalled everything. At least, I think I did. 
I went through Windows Programs and looked for anything that looked like it might be part of Anaconda, python, or Spyder.

I tried reinstalling Anaconda.
I got the 3 error messages about menus, path, and directories (there's a bunch of tickets on those). My path is short (800 characters or so) and my user name is in English.

I uninstalled and tried again.
Same results.
I created and ran the Fix.bat

```
"C:\My_Stuff\Program_Files\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\My_Stuff\Program_Files\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" addpath
"C:\My_Stuff\Program_Files\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\My_Stuff\Program_Files\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkdirs
"C:\My_Stuff\Program_Files\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\My_Stuff\Program_Files\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkmenus
```

and that at least gave me my menus.

From a command prompt (either Anaconda or Windows),

conda list

shows no packages.

Spyder and Anaconda Navigator do not start ("This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".)

Typing python from a command prompt (either one) appears to work and references Anaconda 4.2.0

I'm going around in circles.

Any help appreciated.

Craig

Comment: I'm focusing on conda list being empty, but so far have come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had posted this on Github too, as I ran into a larger problem while trying to get my system back.

The last comment from that thread (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4369) is repeated here:

I have, I believe, successfully installed Anaconda 4.2 64bit Python 3.5 version

I uninstalled the software again using the Windows 10 uninstall from Programs and Features.
I manually removed the Anaconda paths from the user PATH variable.
I manually removed the Anaconda folder from the Startup menu.
I manually removed selected references to Anaconda in the registry.

(I did not see the Anaconda clean program until later - https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install)

I rebooted.
I installed from the exe I had downloaded last year (4.2)
This time, I installed for all users, not just me.

Testing

`conda list

returns many packages. Yeah!

Calling python from a command prompt works too.
Spyder starts and remember my previous project, so that is nice too.

I think I can work again. 
I may need to upgrade some packages, so hopefully that will go well too.

Craig